how to enforce gnuplot to ignore an empty datablock
My script generates a number of data blocks with set table, like
set table $Temp1
plot 'file' u 1:2 w table
unset table

They are generated under some conditions, such that if those conditions are not fulfilled, they remain empty.
At the end of the day, I have to plot them all. Problem is that if any of them is empty, I get an error message when plotting it, namely Column number or datablock line expected rather than just ignoring that datablock which is what I would like.
I've tried Gnuplot, how to *skip* missing data files? but this seems to work only for empty files, not for empty datablocks

Which gnuplot version are you using? How exactly do you try to plot it? If I try to plot an emtpy datablock I don't get an error and the script doesn't stop, but I get a warning: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points and the script continues.

@theozh I use gnuplot 6.1, the same as you I suppose... it may have to do with some other stuff of my script... however I'll try Ethan's solution by now, it seems a good hint. I appreciate however your input.

The cardinality operator |<name>| will return the size of the data block, i.e. the number of lines.
gnuplot> $DATA << EOD
1
2
EOD
gnuplot> $EMPTY << EOD
EOD

gnuplot> data_size = |$DATA|
gnuplot> empty_size = |$EMPTY|
gnuplot> print data_size
2
gnuplot> print empty_size
0
gnuplot> 


Indeed! That simple! Now after plotting 3 files that I'm sure are full, if I replot ONLY 1 of the 2 presumably empty files if |<datablock name>| is not zero, indeed it works ! Then if I replot the other file, it comes out only the latter, the former being replaced by 3 warning messages, namely 'warning: Skipping data file with no valid points' which correspond to the 3 initially plotted files. Or if I just replot, only the latter file is displayed, namely the one obtained with the first replot. Do you guess why without having to show you the whole script ? x-axis is timestamp.

.@Ethan Said in other words: your trick allows me to plot existing files, then to replot any of the presumably void files (provided that they are actually non-void) but not two files; just one. Does that make sense ?

You have not provided any information about why you are using replot, or what these 1, 2, or 3 files contain.  I tried to answer the original question "How to make gnuplot ignore an empty datablock?".   My answer is if (|$datablock| > 0) {  ... do something ... }.  If the datablock is empty it will be ignored. If it is non-empty you can plot it or print it or whatever.

.@Ethan Maybe I should provide my script. I use replot because, first, I've plotted the files that are, for sure, non-empty. Then, if your conditions fulfills for the other two files that might be empty, I replot them. That's your{  ... do something ... }. What is weird is that this works only for the 1st replot, not for the 2nd. The 2nd replot plots that very file, yes, but cannot plot the very first files, those plotted at the very beginning. Instead it displays a 'warning: Skipping data file with no valid points'Hope to arrange my script shortly to open a new question with it

Why replot rather than simply plot?  You can edit the original question to show the script.

.@Ethan Alright, I'll do so. Give me a bit of time. Now, just to answer you... I replot because I need to plot the previous files too, those that were non-empty for sure... I'd like to plot everything at the same time but I cannot when one or two of the presumably empty files are actually empty. So I have to first plot what can be plotted for sure. And then replot,if (|$datablock| > 0), the 2 files that could be empty, one by one. Granted, I could plot everything, together with your condition for each of those 2 files, but then the script becames very large (there would be 4 different cases)

.@Ethan Never mind... I've seen a subtle error I was making... I was plotting the main file, the one that was for sure full, not by name but by plot '' since it had been called just before for evaluating minima and maxima. Now, when I replot once, it's ok. But when I replot twice, it's not ok since '' refers to the last plotted file, which is not the very first one but the first replotted. Lesson learned: it's always more sure to plot a file writing down its name and not using ''. Only if other plots of that very same file are done in the same script line, then '' may be ok for them.
